# How to add Expected delivery time in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

how to add expected delivery time in weeks in magento product view page.i have already insatlled a new theme and want to display delivery time in weeks (e.g 3 weeks)in each product details view.
please help me out from this extremely urgent..

In product view the color and the size is already present.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new product attribute and set it to be shown on the product page. This does mean that you have to set the value manually for each product.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: thanks for replying but i have already added a new attribute delivery_time and set visible to product view page but still cant see this attribute in my themes product view page.

Comment: and after that i am using this code to fetch delivery time and show in frontend.<strong> Delivery Time:
               <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getdelivery_time(), 'delivery_time') ?>
      </strong>

Comment: You should get the attribute value via $_product->getDeliveryTime() or $_product->getData('delivery_time')

Comment: can you please explain me or give me code or describe to how to display the delivery  attribute to the product page view like-Delivery Time : 2 weeks        it already displays the names of the products but do not display the delivery time thats why i want to add that in my new theme.

Comment: The code you need to use is in my previous comment. Maybe you can share your template's code, so we have more information.